# Get value of element created at "future"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check element value if it will be create at the "future" on page.  I know about live method but it works with an event.

Comment: the question is nor very clear. perhaps an example will help.

Comment: what does "at the future" mean? and what is "live method"?

Comment: If that would be possible, I would have already won the lottery, I would just need to remember to put the numbers in the field after the draw.

Comment: live() is probably what you'd use. If your element will be created in the future, presumably its creation is either caused by or can be attached to an event, in which case you can use an event handler in live().

Answer (score 1):

Since `live` requires an event, you could have a look at the [livequery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) for jQuery.

Let's say you want to alert the value of a every dynamically created `<input type="text">` with a class of `foo`, you'd do something like this:

```
$('input[type=text].foo').livequery(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/W7xqk/